# Getting content from url which requires cookies to be enabled

Tags: java, url, cookies

Using java, how do I get the content from a webpage where cookies and javascript are required to load the page?

Comment: SO is not a search engine.

Comment: If cookies and JavaScript are required, then it may mean that the author specifically doesn't want you to do exactly this!

Answer (score 0):

Without code or more information it's hard to help.

You'll want a URLConnection with a CookieHandler, you can find some example code here:

https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/cookie_handling_in_java_se

Answer (score 0):

You should try learning about `HttpURLConnection` and how to send information like cookies to websites via Http headers